# moving variable(columns) to column name (vertical to horizontal) in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix like following table (the matrix is big consists of 16 years suppose for GPA of 100 students A,B,C,D...)

```
  `Year    GPA   Student
1   1996    3.2    A
2   1997    3.3    A
3   1998    3.5    A
4   1999     4     A
5   1996     3     B
6   1997     3     B
7   1998     4     B
8   1999    3.5    B
9   1996     4     C
10  1997     3     C
11  1998     2     C
12  1999     3     C
```

I want to use BICC function in R so I need to change my matrix to something like this :

```
         `A     B     C
 `1996   3.2    3     4
  1997   3.2    3     3
  1998   3.3    4     2
  1999   3.5   3.5    3
```

in this table "Year" variable goes as row (row name ?) and students names go to colname in R .
Thank you .

Comment: Basic reshape long to wide - `reshape(dat, idvar="Year", timevar="Student", direction="wide")`

Comment: Or use the `tidyverse` function `spread()`

Answer (score -1):

We can use `xtabs` from `base R` to do this

```
xtabs(GPA~Year + Student, df1)
#      Student
#Year     A   B   C
#  1996 3.2 3.0 4.0
#  1997 3.3 3.0 3.0
#  1998 3.5 4.0 2.0
#  1999 4.0 3.5 3.0
```

---

Or with `acast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
acast(df1, Year~Student, value.var = "GPA", fun.aggregate = sum)
```

NOTE: with `acast`, we can change the `fun.aggregate` to `sum`, or `mean` or any other function.  In `xtabs`, it does the `sum` for each 'Year', 'Student' combination (if there are duplicates)