# Sampling randomly from an array of dataframes

Tags: r, dplyr

I have created multiple dataframes based on various conditions. Now I would like to sample the different dataframes but I would like to remove the lines once they are sampled. I have tried dplyrs sample_n:

```
sample_n(df, 4)
```

the problem is that this does not remove the lines, would I need some recursive loop that would remove the lines once they are sampled? Or is there some handy function that can help me?

Comment: Please provide a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Have a look at the `modelr` package for the tidyverse approach.

Comment: @akrun the same question was not asked. I did not merely want to sample the dataframe, I need to not sample the same data again once I sample subsequent times.

Comment: I think it could be categorized as a general dupe as was done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689941/moving-variablecolumns-to-column-name-vertical-to-horizontal-in-r/41689954#41689954).  Anyway, I am reopening it if you find it objectionable

Comment: @akrun, I think it was my fault was not elaborating on the title correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works for me.

```
# generate data
a <- data.frame(letters = letters[1:5], var = rnorm(5))
b <- data.frame(letters = letters[6:10], var = rnorm(5))
c <- data.frame(letters = letters[11:15], var = rnorm(5))
xy <- list(a, b, c)

set.seed(357) # set seed for reproducibility
dfsample <- sample(seq_len(length(xy)), 1) # sample out one data.frame

xy[[dfsample]]

  letters         var
1       a  1.51348192
2       b -0.60657737
3       c  0.51828252
4       d -0.05352487
5       e -1.34303266

# remove random row, notice the minus sign in front of the sample
xy[[dfsample]] <- xy[[dfsample]][-sample(1:nrow(xy[[dfsample]]), 1), ]
xy[[dfsample]]

  letters         var
2       b -0.60657737
3       c  0.51828252
4       d -0.05352487
5       e -1.34303266
```

Comment: Any particular reason for `seq_len(length(xy))` instead of `seq_along(xy)`?

Comment: Great response, indeed this could be implemented into a recursive function, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Axeman I rarely pay any attention to that part, so no particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
modelr::crossv_mc(mtcars, 5, 0.5)
```

creates 5 sets of exclusive splits of equal size. They are stored as list columns, and use the `resample` class, which is memory efficient.

> ```
> # A tibble: 5 × 3
>            train           test   .id
>           <list>         <list> <chr>
> 1 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>     1
> 2 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>     2
> 3 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>     3
> 4 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>     4
> 5 <S3: resample> <S3: resample>     5
> ```